# jQuery toggle() is not working after multiple filters selected

Tags: jquery

Having a problem with jQuery toggle.

I'm using it for quality filter.

Trying to filter with jQuery the rows:

```
$( ".f_best" ).click(function(){

  if ($('.productTable').has('.quality_class_a')) {
    $('.productTable tr').has('.quality_class_a').toggle();
  }



});
```

This is typical table row:

Filter salongiõhk

```
        <dt class="uk-text-muted"></dt>
          <dd class="quality_class_a">
              <img src="/test/img/icons/A.png" alt="Kvaliteediklass: Parim (OEM vastav)"/>
              <span class="tooltiptext">Kvaliteediklass: Parim (OEM vastav)</span>
          </dd>
        <b>Mann-filter CUK31003</b>
                                                                             <br />
        <span class="additionalInfo">
                                        <!--<b>Lisainfo:</b> -->Pikkus (mm): 311 | Laius (mm): 220 | Kõrgus (mm): 31 | Filtritüüp: Aktiivsöefilter<span class="264289555_277655395_d"></span>
                      </span>
      </td>
                                                                                                                          <td class="stock-list-price">
            <table class="stock-list-category">
                        <tr class="stock-list-category-item  green-tr " style="display: table-row!important;">
              <td>
                                          POL02
                                    </td>
              <td>L 11 aug  </td>
              <td class="price ">
                  26,91€
              </td>
          </tr>
                          </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

There are three quality classes. Problem is than when i'm clicking on quality input, everything works. But after clicking on Brand filter input for example, then everything conflicts and .toggle() is changing visibility and mixing visible elements up like - some 3-star products are visible and some are not.

Is there any better way for using multiple filters?

Answer (score 0):

`if ($('.productTable').has('.quality_class_a'))` will always be truthy since even when a match is not found a jQuery object is returned and `if(object)` is truthy

Use `length` to see if matches are found

```
if ($('.productTable').has('.quality_class_a').length)
```